# use routerLink inside external html template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am learning routing in angular 2 , In my root app component I am using `template` configuration property to show navigation links in the view.

**app.component.cs**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
              <div style="padding:5px">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li routerLinkActive="active">
                 <a routerLink="home">Home</a>
                </li>

                 <li routerLinkActive="active">
                  <a routerLink="employees">Employees</a>
                 </li>

              </ul>
               <br/>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
             </div>
              `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

If I have more links the above doesn't look clean and maintainable, So Can I use `templateUrl` property instead and have all router navigation links in separate `html` file ? As shown below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'/app/home/navigation_template.html' 
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**navigation_template.html**

```
<div style="padding:5px">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li routerLinkActive="active">
    <a routerLink="home">Home</a>
   </li>                

   <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink="employees">Employees</a>
   </li>                  

  </ul>
   <br/>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have tried that but it doesn't work , I get error saying:

> InternalError: too much recursion Stack trace:

Comment: Yes, why not? That's the standard way.

Comment: @VivekDoshi , I have tried that but it doesn't work , I get error saying `InternalError: too much recursion Stack trace:`.

Comment: @VivekDoshi , I had silly and small typo in url path , I removed an extra forward slash so now it looks `templateUrl:'app/home/navigation_template.html' ` Now it works :) , Thanks for the confirmation that it works.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 2 and more, the best way to do this is to create a specific routing configuration file.

I created app-routing.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes }     from '@angular/router';

/ Redirection route
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/homePage',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'employees',
        component: EmployeesComponent,
    }];


@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

You can then import your AppRoutingModule and when you click on

```
<a routerLink="employees">Employees</a>
```

you will navigate to the right page.

Don't forget to put

```
<base href="/">
```

in your index.html file in the head for telling your router that this is the base URL

Comment: I have defined all routes using `RoutModule` in root module , I am talking about how can I move navigation links in a separate `html` file.

Comment: Ok sorry missunderstood. Of course you can this is niormal way to do it

Comment: If your template file (.html) is in the same directory than your component file, you should replace templateUrl:'/app/home/navigation_template.html' with templateUrl:'./navigation_template.html'

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work , I get error saying `InternalError: too much recursion Stack trace:.` and the browser crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment it made me to check url path again , I had silly and small typo in url path , I removed an extra forward slash so now it looks `templateUrl:'app/home/navigation_template.html' ` Now it works :)